# Getting all files in site collection by content type

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to get all files by content type in the whole site collection?  This is the code I currently have:

```
//Get list of subsites to traverse
            List<string> subsites = getSubSiteList();
            foreach (string siteUrl in subsites)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = new SPSite(siteUrl).OpenWeb())
                {
                    if (web.GetFolder("Pages").Exists)
                    {
                        //Get Pages Folder from subsite                    
                        SPFolder folderCol = web.Folders["Pages"];

                        //Set files in Pages folder
                        SPFileCollection fileCol = folderCol.Files;
                        foreach (SPFile file in fileCol)
                        {
                            //Debug.WriteLine("File in site: " + siteUrl + " file: " + file.Name);
                        }
                    }
                    web.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

In this code I am iterating through all the subsites and going to the "Pages" folder to get a certain page, but I would like to be able to just pull all these files without having to go through each subsite, and getting it by content-type instead of going inside the "Pages" folder and parsing from there.  How would the code look?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [site data query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx).

Other options would be to programmatically leverage the search functionality, but I don't think it's as good as an option; the site data query is literally designed for exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this to get all the sites as well as sub sites
see this MSDN Site for a list of different options you can use.
[How to: Enumerate Sites and Site Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462161.aspx)

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;

for (int i = 0; i < collWebsite.Count; i++)
{
    using (SPWeb oWebsite = collWebsite[i])
    {
        SPListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

        for (int j = 0; j < collList.Count; j++)
        {
            Label1.Text += SPEncode.HtmlEncode(collWebsite[i].Title) + "   "
                + SPEncode.HtmlEncode(collList[j].Title) + "<BR>";
        }
    }
```